# How to combine attributes of like features in Python

Tags: python, arcgis, many-to-one

I have a text file containing Street and Page attributes. Streets may appear in more than one page, here's an example of the way my text file looks now:

**Street**      **Page**

StreetA    3

StreetA    4

StreetA    5

StreetB    21

StreetB    22

Using python I'm trying to combine like roads into one record with each respective page for that road combined into a single attribute. Here's an example of the way I want my text file to look:

**Street**      **Page**

StreetA    3, 4, 5

StreetB    21, 22

If anybody can give me any hints for how to accomplish this using Python I would be very appreciative

Comment: What code do you have so far? Or are you looking for a good introduction to programming (in Python)?

Comment: I'm pretty new to python. I've been playing with some code but I doubt it is worth posting. The basic training I've received so far hasn't touched on anything like this, so I'm just trying to get a basic idea of how this would work and what module I should focus on

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary mapping street names to lists, like so:

```
streets = {}
for line in records:
    street, space, page = line.partition(' ')
    if street not in streets:
        streets[street] = []
    streets[street].append(page)
```

You could then go through the dictionary and output the results.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import collections
streets = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('a_street_page.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        street_name, number = line.split()
        streets[street_name].append(number)
```

What `defaultdict` does is call the factory given to its constructor when you're accessing a key that doesn't exist yet, and assign the result to that key. This prevents you from having to check if the key already exists. Your scenario is exactly what `defaultdict` is for.

Comment: you guys are awesome. I'm pretty new to python so I'll have to do some playing around with these ideas. Thanks!